# What does コテッと mean?

Tags: meaning

the sentence it's from コテッと首をかしげる

Comment: According to the venerable Google Translate, that sentence means *"I will wear my head."* :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

「コテッ（と）」 is an onomatopoeia used to describe a sudden and/or quick lean or fall to one side by an object.

'Thus, 「コテッと首{くび}をかしげる」 means "***to put one's head on one side***".  「コテッと」 would not necessarily need to be translated here.

We have another 「コテッ（と）」 that describes a food item, which means "***very oily***".  These are two different onomatopoeias that happen to be spelt the same.

Ours is a country of mountains, forests, rivers and onomatopoeias.